# completing scratch in react-native-scratch

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I want to reload scratch after completing scratch in react-native-scratch but don't have any solution for that. When I complete my scratch and get my results after that I want scratch it again it's not reset and can't scratch it again.

Answer (score 0):

in react-native-scratch,

in ScratchView.js inside src folder add below method for reset(refill) scratch

```
refresh = () => {

    AnimatedScratchView = RNTScratchView && Animated.createAnimatedComponent(RNTScratchView);
    this.setState({
        isScratchDone: false,
        visible: true
    })
    this.scratchOpacity = {
        opacity: this.state.animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [1, 0],
        }),
    };
}
```

and in top change this const to var

```
var AnimatedScratchView = RNTScratchView && Animated.createAnimatedComponent(RNTScratchView);
```

after that in call this method via reference of child in parent component

```
  <ScratchView
     ref={(ref) => this.scratchRef = ref} />
```

use can use refresh method for reload scratch using "scratchRef" like this:

```
this.scratchRef.refresh();
```